# Valores Booleanos en python

Tags: python, booleano

soy algo nuevo en esto de la programación y tengo una duda sobre como usar los valores booleanos.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
print("tu información personal es correcta?")
correcto =  input("True/False")
info_correcta = True

if info_correcta != correcto:
 print("lo siento mucho, por favor advocate a alguien del personal para que pueda tomar tus datos de 
 forma manual")
```

Lo que quiero hacer practicamente es que el programa le enseñe al usuario su información, luego de que este la vea pues vea si es correcta o no. Pero no se como hacer para que (por ejemplo) si el usuario pone sí el programa siga, o si el usuario pone no, el programa le enseñe ese mensaje. Como se hace?

Answer (score 2):

La función `input()` lee la entrada estándar lo que el usuario haya escrito, y retorna una cadena, es decir, si esperas que el usuario ingrese `True` o `False` el retorno será dicha cadena pero no el valor booleano que la misma representa. Aquí podrás hacer dos cosas:

```
ingreso =  input("True/False: ")
correcto =  True if ingreso.lower() == 'true' else False
```

Con esta estructura ternaria, interpretamos la cadena ingresada tal que si convertida a minúscula es `true`, entonces `correcto` será efectivamente el valor booleano `True` caso contrario será `False`.

La otra forma es similar, solo que obviamos la creación de la variable `correcto` y simplemente verificamos la cadena

```
ingreso =  input("True/False: ")

if ingreso.lower() != 'true':
   print("lo siento mucho, por favor advocate a alguien del personal para que pueda tomar tus datos de 
 forma manual")
```

Comment: Para decir que un valor no es igual a otro en Python se usa el !=, no el <>. Buena respuesta de igual modo!

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido a StackOverflow En Español!

El código puede ser más eficiente así:

```
print("tu información personal es correcta?")
correcto =  int(input("0 Para decir si, otro número para decir no: "))

if correcto == 0:
 print("lo siento mucho, por favor advocate a alguien del personal para que pueda tomar tus datos de 
 forma manual")
```

1er Punto a aclarar: `int(input())` hace que el input sólo acepte datos de tipo int o entero. Si se introduce un dato de otro tipo, saldrá error, pero no importa, lo aprenderás a evitar luego.

2do Punto a aclarar: False significa FALSO y True significa VERDADERO. Estos son los únicos valores que puede tomar un booleano (en el caso de Python). En el caso de usar booleanos en input(), si la cadena esta vacía, se toma como False. Para solucionar esto podemos usar números.

3er Punto a aclarar: Al decir una expresión que contenga un `== True`, este pedazo se puede quitar, por eso digo:

```
if correcto:
```

Ya que es lo mismo que decir:

```
if correcto == True:
```

Esto no pasa con el False.